# Data type and annotation attributes reuse

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a class or something like `string` which can be reused for difference model with data annotation attributes?

Model code:

```
public class Model1
{
    public mytype type1 { get; set; }
    public string type2 { get; set; }
}

public class Model2
{
    public mytype type1 { get; set; }
    public string type2 { get; set; }
}
```

Base Class

```
public class mytype
{
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string mytype { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try exaplaining what do you want better, use some code for example. I did not get what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Comment: are you trying to restrict the `mytype` to be no longer than 20 characters or what?

Comment: The correct answer to your question is "Yes". If you need a more helpful and detailed answer, you need to ask a more helpful and detailed question.

Comment: I want property to have a standard or central class to control the data annotation rather than type it every time.  The annotation is not just string length and others like display format etc.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own data annotations. Here is a link explainig how to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256183/DataAnnotations-Validation-for-Beginner

Comment: be careful when just posting a link to elsewhere. If this post taken out from the web site, your answer will be no longer valid!!

Comment: Thanks!! Is it possible to define as type?  So it can be used as parameter.  like public function1(mytype type1).